# Regular expression ng-pattern angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

I have to validate an input field, but I have problems when the user copy and paste something inside the input

This is my code

```
<input type="text" ng-change="calculate()" ng-pattern="coordsPattern" ng-model="from" class="input-coords" placeholder="(x|y)">
```

where the coordsPattern is:

```
$scope.coordsPattern = /^\(?\-?\d{1,3}\|\-?\d{1,3}\)?$/;
```

the input can take

```
(158|158)  
-158|158  
(-158|158
```

.....etc

but when the user copy and paste the same thing from a different page, depending on browser to browser, the input looks like `(158|158)` but the pattern is invalid because when copying there are hidden tabs or spaces between chars. for example

```
((tab)(tab)158(tab)|(tab)(tab)-158(tab)
```

but in the input text looks like `(158|-158` so for the user is a valid input
the input is valid (because in the `calculate()` function I clean the input from spaces and tabs) but invalid with that pattern and angular doesn't execute the `calculate()` function.

this one is a copy&paste text which includes hidden tabs

```
(‭-‭91‬‬|‭-‭18‬‬)
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

this is the var_dump of the string

```
string '(â€­-â€­91â€¬â€¬|â€­-â€­18â€¬â€¬)' (length=33)
```

it contains special chars! neither tabs or spaces!
maybe I have to find a different solution to validate the input...

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.coordsPattern = /^\s*?\(?\s*?\-?\s*?\d{1,3}\s*?\|\s*?\-?\s*?\d{1,3}\s*?\)?\s*?$/;
```

This should match the expected input even when there are whitespace characters inserted.

Comment: This one doesn't work with the copy&paste. I also tried to change \s in \t, but still not working. Try to copy this string in a text editor ‎‭(‭-‭91‬‬|‭-‭18‬‬) it contains hidden chars (I think tabs or spaces, but maybe special chars)